# PHP 8.1 to 8.2 upgrade not reflecting in laradock workspace

Tags: php, laradock

I upgrade Laradock PHP from 8.1 to 8.2 following [this article](https://cyrildewit.github.io/2020/04/19/how-to-change-the-PHP-version-in-Laradock/) but it does not show 8.2 when I checked the version afterwards.

```
 cd Sites/laradock
 laradock % docker-compose exec workspace bash
    cd paulgodard
       php -v => 8.1.18
       exit
 laradock % docker-compose build php-fpm
 laradock % docker-compose build workspace
```

Then after restarting Docker...

```
 cd Sites/laradock
 laradock % docker-compose exec workspace bash
    cd paulgodard
       php -v => 8.1.18
```

Should I do the upgrade for all projects like paulgodard?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to rebuild the container. Keep in mind that you might want to rebuild the php-fpm container as well